# superfish.css menu height item is not correct (autoadjusted)

Tags: jquery, html, web, superfish

I am working on some website and the web template was purchased. This web template uses file superfish.css and therefore I think this template uses [Superfish plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/superfish/). In this menu, I have some long texts as seen in following screenshot:
[image: Superfish menu]
Now, as you can see, I was forced to wrap texts `Hardware Engineering`, `Software Engineering` and `Embedded Systems` with html command `<br>`, which is now ok, but menu items `Home`, `Pricing` and `Conctacts` are not horizontaly aligned anymore and the currect menu item marker (with red background) is not resized. Why and how do I correct that?

Comment: can u show to this navigation code or create alink in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @RohitAzad hmm I am total noob in webpages world, which file navigation code do you think it is, in `index.html` since there I build a menu?

Comment: Do you publish this code in cloud if yes can u provide me link

Comment: @RohitAzad no problem, but I just do not know WHICH FILE you want to check or I zip you whole website and share it? I was thinking of giving you `index.html`, `style.css` and `superfish.css`, is this ok?